# Displaying all aggregated results from Elasticsearch query in PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a field called "arrivalDate" and this field is a string. Each document has an arrivalDate in string format (ex: 20110128). I want my output to be something like this (date and the number of records that have that date):

> Date : how many records have that date
>
> 20110105 : 5 records
>
> 20120501 : 2 records
>
> 20120602 : 15 records

I already have the query to get these results.

I am trying to display aggregated results in PHP from Elasticsearch. I want my output to be something like this:

Date : how many records have that date

20110105 : 5 records

20120501 : 2 records

20120602 : 15 records
This is what I have so far:

```
    $json = '{"aggs": { "group_by_date": { "terms": { "field": "arrivalDate" } } } }';

        $params = [
            'index' => 'pickups',
            'type' => 'external',
            'body' => $json 
            ];

$results = $es->search($params);
```

However, I don't know how to display the results in PHP. For example, if I wanted to display the total number of documents I would do `echo $results['hits']['total']` How could I display all the dates with the number of records they have in PHP?

Comment: how does your `$results` array looks like?

Comment: @Auris It contains all the information if I had run the script in Kibana. It contains the hits, total, sample documents, and the aggregations of some documents

Comment: @Auris This is the aggregations part of the array, this is only a snippet: [aggregations] => Array ( [group_by_date] => Array ( [doc_count_error_upper_bound] => 11058 [sum_other_doc_count] => 818008 [buckets] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => 20160614 [doc_count] => 18462 ) ) ) ) )

Comment: You can try Alex's answer and do it within the query, but to access data from your sinpet php would look like: `foreach($result['aggregations']['group_by_date']['group_by_date']['buckets'] as $entry) { echo $entry['key'];  echo $entry['doc_count']; }`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using aggregations in the same way you construct the query, from my experience it seems to work quicker. Please see the below code:

```
'aggs' => [
    'group_by_date' => [
        'terms' => [
            'field' => 'arrivalDate',
            'size' => 500
        ]
    ]
]
```

Following that, instead of using the typical `results['hits']['hits']` you would switch out the hits parts to `results['aggregations']`. Then access the returning data by accessing the buckets in the response.

For accessing the data from the aggregation shown above, it would likely be something along the lines of:

```
foreach ($results as $result){
    foreach($result['buckets'] as $record){
        echo($record['key']);
    }
}
```

There will be a better way of accessing the array within the array, however, the above loop system works well for me. If you have any issues with accessing the data, let me know.